# How to update a single property of the state in a react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to change a state hook and I got this error... I know another way to change but it should work with the spread syntax, right?

```js
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = {
    sld_url: "",
    geojson_url: "",
  }

  const handleSldUrlChange = event => {
    setState({...state, sld_url: event.target.value})
  }

  return (
    <TextField
     label="SLD URL"
     value={state.sld_url}
     className={classes.textField}
     onChange={handleSldUrlChange}
     margin="normal"
     variant="outlined"
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: There are no hooks being used anywhere in your code, so what's your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing is you need to [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) :

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    sld_url: "",
    geojson_url: "",
  })
```

Than inside `handleSldUrlChange function` you can use a custom callback for updating state

```
const handleSldUrlChange = event => {
    setState(prev => {...prev, sld_url: event.target.value})
   //or
   //setState({...state,sld_url: event.target.value})
  }
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mv8lsz

Comment: Perhaps you mean 

const handleSldUrlChange = event => {
    setState({...state, sld_url: event.target.value})
  }

Comment: Yeah its another way of writing it. I wrote in callback just like react **setState** one. Or you suggested is basically update object using spread. Not big difference. Thanks will update this way also